# Define size for small image size in magento community

Tags: image, magento, php, image-size

After uploading an image in magento  by default in a small_image folder it creates copies it in these resolutions 100x100; 125x125; 180x240; 75x100
I need it to also create it in 180x180
If edit `list.phtml` to display images in a square it inserts a rectangular image into a square and you can see white boarders on left and right.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(180); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

try above code in list.phtml.

hope this help